Почему бот на питоне не выводит сообщения, но при этом создается файл с sql разрешением
import telebot 
import sqlite3

bot = telebot.TeleBot('bot_token') 
name = None

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start']) 
def start(message):
    conn= sqlite3.connect('base.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF EXISTS users (id int auto_increment primary key, name varchar(50), pass varchar(50))')
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, для регистрации напиши свое имя!')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_name)

def user_name(message):
    global name
    name = message.text.strip()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ВВедите пароль')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_pass)

def user_pass(message):
    password = message.text.strip()
    conn= sqlite3.connect('base.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute(f' INSEPT INFO users (name, pass) VALUES ({name}, {password})')
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    marcup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    marcup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('Список пользователей.', callback_data='users'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пользователь зарегестрирован!', reply_markup=marcup)
    


bot.polling(none_stop=True)


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

И ошибок никаких не выходит? Может код падает с исключением?

CREATE TABLE IF EXISTS ?
